# Can i input duplicate values in foreign key column

Tags: microsoft-access, ms-sql

A small but important question can input null and duplicate values in foreign key column connected with some another table with same column identity and values as far of my knowledge it is not possible if it is possible let me know

Answer (score 0):

Reading the wikipedia definition for [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) will answers your question.

In particular, it confirms that

> Multiple rows in the referencing (or child) table may refer to the same row in the referenced (or parent) table. In this case, the relationship between the two tables is called a one to many relationship between the referenced table and the referencing table.

Comment: I dont understand what you said but probably i can try for some help which is related to my question

Comment: Have you read the definition I linked. It answers your questions ... and more.